# Error using ggmcmc package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `ggmcmc` package to produce a summary pdf file of `rjags` package output using the `ggmcmc()` function.  However, I get the following error message:

```
> ggmcmc(x, file = "Model0-output.pdf")
Plotting histograms
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 160, 164
```

When I check the structure of the input dataframe I created with the `ggs()` function, everything looks to be correct.

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   240000 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Iteration: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ Chain    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Parameter: Factor w/ 32 levels "N[1]","N[2]",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ value    : num  96 87 76 79 89 95 85 78 86 89 ...
- attr(*, "nChains")= int 3
- attr(*, "nParameters")= int 32
- attr(*, "nIterations")= int 2500
- attr(*, "nBurnin")= num 2000
- attr(*, "nThin")= num 2
- attr(*, "description")= chr "postout0"
- attr(*, "parallel")= logi FALSE
```

Can anyone help me identify where the error is being caused and how I can correct it?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

ggmcmc 0.5.1 solves the calculation of the number of bins in a different manner that it did it in previous versions. Previous versions relied on ggplot2:::bin, whereas 0.5.1 computes the bins and their binwidth by itself.

It is likely your case that the range of some of the parameters was so extreme that rounding errors would make some of them have one more or one less bins, therefore producing this error.